# Android - How to avoid onResume of fragments when popping them from the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

We have multiple screens in our app and to switch between them we use FragmentTransactions, primarily replace, and we add fragments to the backstack when we do so. While doing so we stay within the same MainActivity.

So if we transition from Fragment A to Fragment B via some button we now have a stack that looks like

B
A

If we go to another Fragment C it goes on top of the stack like so

C
B
A

However, sometimes we transition to a fragment D, such that we want to wipe out the backstack so that users can no longer navigate back through C, B, A. We now want our backstack after navigating to D to look like this.

D

But in order to do so we need to clear the backstack using:

```
FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
while(supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
{
  supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
}
clearingBackStack = false;
```

But when we do so, the onResume of fragments C,B and A are called. This is not the functionality we intend and can have negative consequences such as making unnecessary server calls. We have also noticed on low end devices that we see a flash of the popped fragments as they come off the stack.

We wish to avoid this behavior, is there a way to pop the entire fragment backstack without the popped fragments being activated in anyway?

Comment: You want to change the `onResume` behavior, why not override the method?

Comment: We looked into something like that with an ugly bool flag but we need to suppress more than just the onResume, we're also seeing visual flashes of the fragment as it is popped off the stack and altering onResume does not fix that.

Comment: Have you tried popBackStackImmediate(A_back_stack_name, 0); ?

Comment: That does not change the behavior from what I can tell, the onResume is still called.